# SELECT * FROM WHERE (using column from another table)

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in MySQL, 1st table is called "receipt" the 2nd one is "scoreboard"

receipts Table:

[image]

Here is the scoreboard table >>

[image]

I need SQL to select from COL 7 where [COL3] = [scorekey] AND [COL 5] = [Selection]

and echo to div `echo "<div>". $scr["COL 7"] ."</div>"`

I tried join the two table, and my code is not working:

```
$score = "SELECT COL7
FROM scoreboard
LEFT JOIN scorekey ON receipts
WHERE scoreboard = scorekey";


$scr = $connection->query($score);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT s.[COL 7] as some_name
FROM scoreboard s
INNER JOIN receipts r ON s.COL3 = r.scorekey 
                     AND s.[COL 5] = r.Selection
```

Comment: how do I echo this its giving me : Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\Mobile\mybets.php on line 94  I tried using : <?php



    echo'

    <td>'. $scr["COL 7"] .'</td> 


'

?>

Comment: I updated the answer. Use `as`  to give the column another name in your query ouput. You can echo that. Don't use spaces or special characters as a new name.